# attempting to do custom calculations for an Adobe fillable form, but getting NaN

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm trying to do some basic math calculations to get the total of my form. The problem I'm running into is when a checkbox is not being checked, code is not working. It works when all three are checked though. The checkboxes are mon, tue and wed.

There is probably something wrong with my javascript syntax...

```
var conf = this.getField("conference"); 
var conf_check = false;

if(conf.value == 3 || conf.value == 4){
  conf_check = true;
}

switch (conf.value) {
  case 1: result = 625; break;
  case 2: result = 850; break;
  case 3: result = 220; break;
  case 4: result = 275; break;
  default: result = 0;
}

if(conf_check == true){
  var total_multiplier = 0;
  if(this.getField("mon").value != "NaN"){

    total_multiplier = total_multiplier + this.getField("mon").value;
  }

  if(this.getField("tue").value !="NaN"){
    total_multiplier = total_multiplier + this.getField("tue").value;
  }

  if(this.getField("wed").value != "NaN"){
    total_multiplier = total_multiplier + this.getField("wed").value;
  }

  var total = total_multiplier * result;

} else {

  total = result;

}

event.value = total;
```

Basically if there is one NaN checkbox it ruins the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

He is a check function in javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>
function validate(chk){
  if (chk.checked == 1)
    alert("Thank You");
  else
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
  chk.checked = 1; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type=checkbox name=chk1>Please Check Me
<p><input type=button value="check" onclick="return validate(chk1);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13204

Comment: Mark thanks for the formatting. I am new to stackoverflow. Will try to format better on next post. Any tips for pasting code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests will always pass, even when the value is NaN.  First, I'm not so sure isNaN("NaN") == true.

Second:  NaN != NaN.  You must use isNaN() instead of ==.

Not A Number is not equal to Not A Number.